# Config method does not work in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
<tr>
<td>Please <a style="color:blue; text-decoration: underline;" href="{{url(Config::get('secure.url'))}}password/{{$token}}">Click here </a>to reset your password</td>
</tr>
```

Why this is adding null/xyz.example.com/password/3434xdsfs33

Why it is adding null value before the url please guide thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel helpers or some class method in your config file you must have an error. You must set your variable value as string and get if with config() helper.

```php
<?php
   return [
      "url"=>"/test/url"
   ]
```

Your Blade

```php
<tr>
   <td>Please <a href="{{url(config('custom.url'))}}password/{{$token}}">Click here </a> to reset your password</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes I do have file secure.php under config folder and  return [
      "url"=>"xyz.example.com"
   ]
Besides this getting getting null/xyz.example.com

Comment: @Viru45 Can i see your secure.php file? But you called custom file and url attribute... if your file name is secure you must use config('secure.url')

Comment: yeah i noticed but have written wrong but that's not a problem i'm using same secure.php with same array updated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `config\app.php` file, for example under the `'url'` entry:

```
'custom_url' => env('CUSTOM_URL', 'http://xyz.example.com'),
```

Then, adding this to your `.env` file, which should be in your Laravel project root:

```
CUSTOM_URL=http://xyz.example.com
```

Then, using this in your code:

```
<tr>
<td>Please <a style="color:blue; text-decoration: underline;" href="{{Config::get('custom_url')}}password/{{$token}}">Click here </a>to reset your password</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why do we need env file let's say i don't use env file then ?? But i can see in my app.php url => 'xyz.example.com' exists does this creating problem ??

Comment: @Viru45 the reason you'd want to use an env file, is so that your code doesn't end up in your source code repository. That's bad practice since if someone happens to get a hold of your source code, all your environment variables (which usually include secrets and passwords and tokens and such) would be exposed. Check principle 3 of the 12-factor app methodology. https://www.bmc.com/blogs/twelve-factor-app/

the xyz.example.com is a default that Laravel uses if it can't find your .env file, or can't find the CUSTOM_URL variable in the .env file.